# С++ декларация копирующего конструктора без определения. Зачем и как работает?

Tags: c++, конструктор

Нашёл в чужом коде public декларацию копирующего конструктора класса без определения. Не могу сообразить зачем это нужно и как работает. Компилятор ругается, что неявный оператор копирования запрещён этой конструкцией, но программу запускает и выполняет по виду так, словно неявно создан оператор присваивания, а при обращении к конструктору копирования вылетает ошибка при линковке. То есть это такой старинный способ запретить использование копирующего конструктора? Или что-то ещё делает такая декларация?

Параметры компиляции С++(14)GNU:

```bsh
g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++14 -pedantic-errors
```

Пример программы:

```
#include <iostream> 

class SomeClass
{
private:
    int m_iNum{10};
public:
    SomeClass(void);
    SomeClass(SomeClass&);    // что меняет эта декларация?
    void SetInt(int const iNum);
    int GetInt(void){return m_iNum;}
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass c1;
    SomeClass c2;
//  SomeClass c3{c1}; // ошибка: prog.cc:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&)'

    c1.SetInt(1);

    c2 = c1; // OK

    std::cout << "c1.m_iNum = " << c1.GetInt() << "\n";
    std::cout << "c2.m_iNum = " << c2.GetInt() << "\n";

    return 0;
}

SomeClass::SomeClass(void)
{
    std::cout << "SomeClass explicit default constructor\n";
}

void SomeClass::SetInt(int const iNum)
{
    m_iNum = iNum;
}
```

Результат:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:22:7: warning: implicitly-declared 'constexpr SomeClass& SomeClass::operator=(const SomeClass&)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
   22 |  c2 = c1; // OK
      |       ^~
prog.cc:9:2: note: because 'SomeClass' has user-provided 'SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&)'
    9 |  SomeClass(SomeClass&);    // что меняет эта декларация?
      |  ^~~~~~~~~

SomeClass explicit default constructor
SomeClass explicit default constructor
c1.m_iNum = 1
c2.m_iNum = 1
```

Comment: В смысле что она меняет????? может он там стоял с = delete?

Comment: Вообще-то именно так и запрещалось ранее копирование. Только еще и объявление конструктора переносилось в раздел `private`.

Comment: @Harry если с delete, без разницу в какой она секции

Comment: @Andrey Цитирую сам себя: *Вообще-то именно так и запрещалось* **ранее** *копирование.* Вопросов больше нет?

Comment: @Harry я Вам о Фоме, Вы мне про Ерему,,,,,

Comment: @Andrey Скорее я написал про Ерему, но вам очень захотелось что-то написать - а писать про Ерему нечего. Вот вы про Фому и написали :) Пришлось напомнить, что я писал про Ерему... А если грубо - то я написал про бабушку, а вы дописали "а если б у нее был .ер и борода - то она была бы дедушкой" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Компилятор ругается, что неявный оператор копирования запрещён этой конструкцией

Компилятор информирует, что генерация неявного оператора копирования в такой ситуации *будет* запрещена когда-то в будущем, но пока что *не запрещена*.

Это будет заметный breaking change, то есть есть вероятность того, что в подвешенном состоянии deprecated она будет находится еще долго. По крайней мере в реализациях.

Пока что объявление копирующего конструктора без определения неявно удаляет лишь перемещающий конструктор и перемещающий оператор присваивания. Во всем остальном это просто объявление без определения.

> при обращении к конструктору копирования вылетает ошибка при линковке.

То есть таким способом мы получаем некий "доморощенный" способ запретить использование конструктора копирования. Зачем понадобилось делать именно так - не ясно.

В "классическом" С++ запрет не использование конструктора копирования достигался путем объявления его `private` (после чего его можно было не определять). В современном С++ это лучше делать через определение конструктора как `= delete`.

То, что написано у вас, похоже на "классический" вариант с `private`, в котором просто забыли `private`. Вы уверены, что правильно воспроизвели код?

Comment: Да, код совершенно такой в том что касается конструктора. Так как код, судя по всему, по очереди писало много человек (aka "коллективная разработка"), то что имели в виду и имели ли что либо вообще в виду теперь сложно установить. )) Спасибо большое за ответ. Я не был уверен нет ли какого-то сакрального смысла в этой конструкции ))